# Why is R deleting all the information in my files when I try to run a for loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2

I have a modelling program prepared which produces 26 separate files that I need to contour plot in the same way in R - I am planning on running this program repeatedly, and hence have been trying to create a loop which creates and saves plots for all 26 files for each run.

At the moment when I run the function for creating the plot, it removes all the data from the input spreadsheet (i.e. file size goes from 1.2Mb to 0Mb) - it wasn't doing this previously, can anyone explain what is going wrong?

Sample of my data:

```
Z    X     T
0    0     0
0    0.005 0
0    0.01  0
0    0.015 0
```

(and so on for 84k rows)

My code:

```
# List all files in folder to be plotted
filenames <- list.files(path=".",
                    pattern="csv", 
                    full.names=TRUE)

#Creates a contour plot in ggplot of the variable in xz space
makeplot <- function(filename) {
data <- read.csv(file = filename)

ggplot(data=data, mapping = aes(x = data[,2], 
                              y = data[,1], 
                              z = data[,3])) +

geom_raster(data=data, aes(fill=data[,3]), show.legend=TRUE, interpolate = 
FALSE) +
scale_fill_gradient(limits=range(data[,3]), high = 'red', low = 'white') +
geom_contour(bins = 50, colour = "black") +
xlab(label = "Distance from ridge axis") +
ylab(label = "Depth") +
theme_classic()+
coord_cartesian(
  ylim = c(0,1), xlim = c(0,2))+
scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) + 
scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0, 0)) +
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="Yb concentration")) +
theme(legend.position="bottom")

}

# Repeat plotting
for(f in filenames) {
    makeplot(f)
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you claiming that R is modifying the CSV files? Because there is nothing in your code that would do that.

Comment: It appears to be doing that yes

Comment: 1) Where does it remove the data? I.e., is original spreadsheet now blank, or is your df in R blank? And 2), you do not have code for saving your 26 files. Could you be overwriting the filenames?

Comment: The original spreadsheet went blank - but I appear to have sorted it now.